# How to prevent on-screen keyboard from focusing on last window minimize by it

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I like to use on-screen keyboard a lot but there's an annoying problem.

If I use Google Chrome (for example) and minimize it using the on-screen keyboard, then minimize the on-screen keyboard and open another program like notepad (on-screen keyboard should stay focused on notepad ) it maximizes Google Chrome so I have to click on notepad again.

It seems the on-screen keyboard controls the open windows order, and the on-screen keyboard focus sticks on the last window minimize with it instead of focusing on last window when I click on it to maximize.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have traced this extremely annoying bug all the way back to Windows XP, so this is in fact now a 17 year old bug that has still not been fixed(!).

This bug is also discussed here, but the thread is locked and you can't discuss this issue any further:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/how-to-prevent-on-screen-keyboard-from-focus-on/2e6c7d6b-f59e-4b95-b37e-487ff33dbda3

I managed to create a simple fix by loading `osk.exe` into x64dbg, analyzing what the problem was, and then patching the code using the debugger (see below for instructions).

What is happening is that `osk.exe` is continuously storing the last active window in order to focus this window when the mouse hovers over OSK, or the user happens to activate OSK. This keeps the focus on the last active window at all times, which ensures that when you type with OSK the input goes where it should.

The problem is `osk.exe` stops storing the active window when OSK is minimized.

This is the bug.

Now when you restore a minimized OSK it has amnesia, and only remembers the last active window from before it was minimized. So now it will focus this old window, instead of the previous real active window.

The "fix" that I used was to simply prevent OSK from ever forcing any window to become focused. You only have to patch one byte in `osk.exe` for this fix, and that's why I chose it. Any other patch would have been extremely complicated otherwise.

In x64dbg you simply search for all references to `SetForegroundWindow`. There are only two calls to this Win32 method. The first reference is the one to patch. There's an instruction `push eax` just before the call to `SetForegroundWindow`. Just replace `push eax` with `ret`, save to `osk.exe`, and replace the original `osk.exe` with this patched version.

[image: x64dbg view of osk.exe]

Problem solved.

It's not a 100% solution, because the auto-activate convenience of OSK is lost, but it's still better this way without the original annoyance. The auto-activation can be restored with AutoHotKey instead.

Leave a message here and I will post the script if anyone needs it. With the patch + AHK script, you have a fully working OSK without the annoying original bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Windows 10 Pro x64 Version 2004

Thanks @Casper so much for his answer. I do not know how to use x64dbg to search for references but found that after attaching to `osk.exe`, doing `bp SetForegroundWindow` and continuing execution minimizing/restoring osk, two occurrences were found by the breakpoint but the osk code looked different than @Casper's. Replacing both the calls by 0x90 (NOOPs) fixed the problem. Each call was 7 bytes so two runs of 7 NOP instructions did the trick.

I chose to copy osk.exe to my own folder rather than hacking the one in C:\Windows\System32 which could look like a virus to some scanners.

Note that osk.exe switches itself to administrator and x64dbg will ask to restart as administrator when attaching to it. This could also cause a "A referral was returned from the server" error when launching your patched copy depending on your ValidateAdminCodeSignatures policy. Right-click on your patched osk.exe, properties, Compatibility, "Run this program as an administrator" solves this.

Here are the differences:

```
D:\Utils>fc /b osk.exe "osk - Copy.exe"
Comparing files osk.exe and OSK - COPY.EXE
0000921A: 90 48
0000921B: 90 FF
0000921C: 90 15
0000921D: 90 87
0000921E: 90 5E
0000921F: 90 01
00009220: 90 00
0000A56E: 90 48
0000A56F: 90 FF
0000A570: 90 15
0000A571: 90 33
0000A572: 90 4B
0000A573: 90 01
0000A574: 90 00
```

With a hex editor you can edit osk.exe and go to those offsets and if the bytes in the second column match what's in your file just replace them with 90 (hex) instead. Since @Casper got away with patching only the first call (with a ret) it's possible only the first 7 NOOPs are required but in my case all 14 were needed. The two SetForegroundWindow calls are rather close to each other so if there's no ret in between them, the NOOPs allow the entire function to run through normally skipping only the SetForegroundWindow calls.

With this hack, the keyboard has the focus when restored (unminimized) instead of the app you want to type into so still not perfect.

Edit: Changing only the second call, last 7 bytes starting at offset A56E seems to work.

Comment: FWIW here's a Windows 10 discussion of this bug: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/164268-screen-keyboard-bug-changes-foreground-window.html#post2016767

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing, stumbled upon this.

https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/263571-unwanted-behavior-screen-keyboard-bug.html

Apparently the bug is known at least since 2013. I don't think there's a fix ready.

Comment: Your answer is good for a comment kindly edit your answer and explain

Comment: My answer would be excellent for a comment, except I cannot comment on posts on SuperUser yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this annoying bug, the easiest solution for me was to pin the on-screen keyboard shortcut to the task bar, and instead of minimizing it, I close it. Then to re-open the virtual keyboard on another window, I simply click again on the shortcut in the task bar, since it has the same effect as if I was clicking on the minimised button. There is no real need or advantages to minimize it rather than close it.